# Create a record for two models in one statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a more-concise way of writing this:

```
> e = Entity.create(name: 'foo')
#<Entity id: 1, name: "foo", created_at: "2014-07-25 13:57:08", updated_at: "2014-07-25 13:57:08">

> l = Location.create(address: 'New York, NY')
#<Location id: 1, address: "New York, NY", created_at: "2014-07-25 13:57:08", updated_at: "2014-07-25 13:57:08">

> e.location = l
> e.save
```

This doesn't work:

```
> Entity.create(name: 'foo').location.create(address: 'New York, NY')
```

Entity `has_one` Location, if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `has_one` association, you can use `create_association`, so for yours, this should work:

```
Entity.create(name: 'foo').create_location(address: 'New York, NY')
```

The [Rails Guide on assocations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one) has a list of these methods that are added automatically.

I'd probably still use the other answer, though, as that will make it easier to created the nested location through a form, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong as I've never tried via command line but I see no reason if you add

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :location` to entity

That you couldn't then do:

```
Entity.create(name: 'foo', location_attributes: {address: 'New York, NY'})
```